# Vue.js pass form data (v-model) values from Parent to Child?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a two component form using vue.js where the parent form starts the multistep process and collects two inputs using v-model and if these are valid values the form moves to the next component of the form using a child component. What I would like to do is take the parent 2 values and append them to the child component formData object for submission. Is there a way to pass the values to the child component? I'm assuming props but not sure how to just pass values and not $emit a function.

Parent:

```
 <div class="row--flex">
            <input type="text" class="form-input text-input center-margin" name="deductibleCardId" id="deductibleCardId" v-model="$v.formData.deductibleCardId.$model" />
  
       <input type="text" class="form-input text-input center-margin" name="savingsCardId" id="savingsCardId" v-model="$v.formData.savingsCardId.$model" />
        </div>

//child component call
 <GetCard v-if="showDemographics" :is-sub-form="true" @submit="submitDemographics" />

 data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        hasCard: null,
        deductibleCardId: null,
        savingsCardId: null
      }
  }
```

Child Component form data:

```
const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('method', 'activate')

        (have these two values be brought over from parent values)

        formData.append('card_hd', this.formData.deductibleCardId)
        formData.append('card', this.formData.savingsCardId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Props are what you want. Something like this, assuming your two values are `deductibleCardId` and `savingsCardId` and are both String type:

**Parent Component:**

```
<GetCard :deductibleCardId='deductibleCardId' :savingsCardId='savingsCardId'>
```

**Child Component:**

```
props: {
  deductibleCardId: String,
  savingsCardId: String,
}
```

From here, you can do whatever you want with these values in your child component using `this.deductibleCardId` and `this.savingsCardId`. For example, you can append them to your formData:

```
formData.append('card_hd', this.deductibleCardId);
formData.append('card', this.savingsCardId);
```

You do not need to emit anything to pass this data from parent to child. In order to pass something back "up" to the parent, you would need to use `emit` or communicate the data using some other strategy available in the Vue ecosystem.